# Create OOTB Tab structure for Different Views

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view, modern-experience, quick-links

I want to implement a functionality where there are different tabs/buttons and on each tab click a specific ListView will be displayed to the user.

It is a modern Communication site. We have a total of 5 views on the list. so plan is to have 5 buttons that will display the respective view below the button. something like this.

With the help of quick links, I can create the buttons as below but how to render the view on each button click and hide the rest of the views?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could add a link via from a link, copy and paste view url in this link, insert it:

[image]

Then change the image for your requirement:

[image]

Each time you click the image with the link or open it in new window, it will redirect to the view you specified, currenlty we could not hide other links in the quick links web part.